# Brazilian shipping adress normalization status

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm facing an issue with the integration of the paypal PHP Api on my website.
When i try to buy something with a brazilian sandbox account when going to my paypal_payment_succes.php page i get the following error when executing the payment:

```html
{"name":"VALIDATION_ERROR","details":[{"field":"transactions[0].item_list.shipping_address.normalization_status","issue":"Field name is not defined for this resource type."}],"message":"Invalid request. See details.","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors","debug_id":"e0f0cecbd95f3"}
```

It seems to be an issue with the adress normalization but i'm not able to solve it on my own.

Here is the creation of the request:

```html
$payer = new \PayPal\Api\Payer();
$payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
$list = new \PayPal\Api\ItemList();
$item = new \PayPal\Api\Item();
$item->setName("myItem");
$item->setPrice($iten_ht_price);
$item->setCurrency('EUR');
$item->setQuantity(1);
$list->addItem($item);
$details = new \PayPal\Api\Details();
$details->setSubtotal($iten_ht_price);
$details->setTax($item_taxes);
$amount = new \PayPal\Api\Amount();
$amount->setTotal($item_ttc_price);
$amount->setCurrency('EUR');
$amount->setDetails($details);
$transaction = new \PayPal\Api\Transaction();
$transaction->setItemList($list);
$transaction->setDescription($service_info["NAME"]);
$transaction->setAmount($amount);
$redirectUrls = new \PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls();
$redirectUrls->setReturnUrl("https://example.com/paypal_payment_success.php")
->setCancelUrl("https://example.com/paypal_payment_cancel.php");
$payment = new \PayPal\Api\Payment();
$payment->setIntent('sale')
  ->setPayer($payer)
  ->setTransactions(array($transaction))
  ->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
try {
  $payment->create($apiContext);
  ?>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  window.location.href = '<?php echo $payment->getApprovalLink(); ?>';
  </script>
  <?php
}
```

and here is the payment validation:

```html
 $payment = \PayPal\Api\Payment::get($_GET['paymentId'], $apiContext);
$execution = new \PayPal\Api\PaymentExecution();
$execution->setPayerId($_GET["PayerID"])
  ->setTransactions($payment->getTransactions());
try {
  $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
}
catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) {
  echo '<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>'.$l["error_happend"].'</strong></div>';
  echo $ex->getData();
  error_log("paypal_payment_success.php error: ". $ex->getData());
}
```

here is the full content of the $payment variable:

```html
PayPal\Api\Payment::__set_state(array(
   '_propMap' => 
  array (
    'id' => 'PAYID-LR6OIAQ8K6195799T910831S',
    'intent' => 'sale',
    'state' => 'created',
    'cart' => '8GR605689F1809928',
    'payer' => 
    PayPal\Api\Payer::__set_state(array(
       '_propMap' => 
      array (
        'payment_method' => 'paypal',
        'status' => 'VERIFIED',
        'payer_info' => 
        PayPal\Api\PayerInfo::__set_state(array(
           '_propMap' => 
          array (
            'email' => 'billing-brazil1@example.com',
            'first_name' => 'Mg',
            'last_name' => 'Doctor',
            'payer_id' => 'LQX9UCM6YMM96',
            'shipping_address' => 
            PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress::__set_state(array(
               '_propMap' => 
              array (
                'recipient_name' => 'Mg Doctor',
                'line1' => '1234 Rua Main',
                'city' => 'Rio De Janeiro',
                'state' => 'RJ',
                'postal_code' => '22021-001',
                'country_code' => 'BR',
                'normalization_status' => 'UNNORMALIZED_USER_PREFERRED',
              ),
            )),
            'tax_id_type' => 'BR_CPF',
            'tax_id' => '30949017787',
            'country_code' => 'BR',
          ),
        )),
      ),
    )),
    'transactions' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      PayPal\Api\Transaction::__set_state(array(
         '_propMap' => 
        array (
          'amount' => 
          PayPal\Api\Amount::__set_state(array(
             '_propMap' => 
            array (
              'total' => '2.50',
              'currency' => 'EUR',
              'details' => 
              PayPal\Api\Details::__set_state(array(
                 '_propMap' => 
                array (
                  'subtotal' => '2.00',
                  'tax' => '0.50',
                ),
              )),
            ),
          )),
          'payee' => 
          PayPal\Api\Payee::__set_state(array(
             '_propMap' => 
            array (
              'merchant_id' => 'WTK64MCV7B6NC',
              'email' => 'billing-facilitator@example.com',
            ),
          )),
          'description' => 'SeedBox Starter',
          'custom' => '57|6|1|2.50|NEW',
          'item_list' => 
          PayPal\Api\ItemList::__set_state(array(
             '_propMap' => 
            array (
              'items' => 
              array (
                0 => 
                PayPal\Api\Item::__set_state(array(
                   '_propMap' => 
                  array (
                    'name' => 'SeedBox Starter | Achat | 1 mois',
                    'price' => '2.00',
                    'currency' => 'EUR',
                    'quantity' => 1,
                  ),
                )),
              ),
              'shipping_address' => 
              PayPal\Api\ShippingAddress::__set_state(array(
                 '_propMap' => 
                array (
                  'recipient_name' => 'Mg Doctor',
                  'line1' => '1234 Rua Main',
                  'city' => 'Rio De Janeiro',
                  'state' => 'RJ',
                  'postal_code' => '22021-001',
                  'country_code' => 'BR',
                  'normalization_status' => 'UNNORMALIZED_USER_PREFERRED',
                ),
              )),
            ),
          )),
          'related_resources' => 
          array (
          ),
        ),
      )),
    ),
    'redirect_urls' => 
    PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls::__set_state(array(
       '_propMap' => 
      array (
        'return_url' => 'https://example.com/paypal_payment_success.php?paymentId=PAYID-LR6OIAQ8K6195799T910831S',
        'cancel_url' => 'https://example.com/paypal_payment_cancel.php',
      ),
    )),
    'create_time' => '2019-03-04T08:38:26Z',
    'update_time' => '2019-03-04T08:38:45Z',
    'links' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      PayPal\Api\Links::__set_state(array(
         '_propMap' => 
        array (
          'href' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LR6OIAQ8K6195799T910831S',
          'rel' => 'self',
          'method' => 'GET',
        ),
      )),
      1 => 
      PayPal\Api\Links::__set_state(array(
         '_propMap' => 
        array (
          'href' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAYID-LR6OIAQ8K6195799T910831S/execute',
          'rel' => 'execute',
          'method' => 'POST',
        ),
      )),
      2 => 
      PayPal\Api\Links::__set_state(array(
         '_propMap' => 
        array (
          'href' => 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-8GR605689F1809928',
          'rel' => 'approval_url',
          'method' => 'REDIRECT',
        ),
      )),
    ),
  ),
))
```

In advance thank you :)

Comment: This needs more details, such as the full response bodies to both the 'create' and 'execute' requests

Comment: Edited with all the information missing :)

Comment: `->setTransactions($payment->getTransactions());`

Is this necessary? Have the transactions changed? Try w/o